why the 'react-countdown' does reset when I click on a button of web page?
This is the code of the quiz-pageyour text
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import "./Quizpage.css"
import QuizQuestionCard from '../../Components/QuizQuestionCard/QuizQuestionCard';
import { userContext } from '../../Context/Context';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { ChartsLegend } from '@mui/x-charts/ChartsLegend';
import QuizTimer from '../../Components/QuizTimer/QuizTimer';


const Quizpage = () => {
  const {state} = useLocation();
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [questionIndex, setQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [ansMap, setAnsMap] = useState(new Map());
  const [marks, setMarks] = useState(0);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [marksPerQues, setMarksPerQues] = useState(0);
  const [negMarksPerQues, setNegMarksPerQues] = useState(0);

  const {account} = useContext(userContext);
  //new start from here
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const countdownRef = useRef();
  //new till here
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`; 
  
  
  
  useEffect(()=>{
     const fetch = async() =>{
        try {
            const id = state?.data?.id;
            console.log("id:",id);
            const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/quiz/quizById",{quizID:state?.data?.id}); 
            console.log("res",res);
            setQuestions(res?.data?.newQuiz?.questions);
            setDuration(res?.data?.newQuiz?.duration);
            setMarksPerQues(res?.data?.newQuiz?.marks);
            setNegMarksPerQues(res?.data?.newQuiz?.negMarks);
        } catch (error) {
          if(error.response && error.response.status===400)
              toast.error(error.response.data.message);
          else
              toast.error(error.message);
          const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            navigate('/protected/home',{replace:true})
          }, 5000);
        }
     }
     fetch();
  },[state, navigate])

 

  const handleSubmit = async() =>{
    try {
      setIsSubmitted(true);
      countdownRef.current.pause(); 
      alert('Quiz submitted!');
      const data = {

      }
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/studentRecord/addStudentRecord",{quizID:state?.data?.id,username:account?.username,marks:marks,totalMarks:`${marksPerQues>0 ? questions?.length*marksPerQues : 1}`});
      navigate("/protected/result",{state:{marks:marks,totalMarks:questions?.length}})
    } catch (error) {
      if(error?.response && error?.response?.status===400)
              toast.error(error?.response?.data?.message);
      else
              toast.error(error.message);
    }
  }

  const handleTimerComplete = async() => {
      if (!isSubmitted) {
          setIsSubmitted(true);
          alert('Time is up! Submitting your quiz.');
          // const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/studentRecord/addStudentRecord",{quizID:state?.data?.id,username:account?.username,marks:marks,totalMarks:questions?.length});
          // navigate("/protected/result",{state:{marks:marks,totalMarks:questions?.length}})
      }
  };

  return (
    <div className='quiz-page-container'>
        
        <div className='quiz-page-left'>
            <div className='question-pointers'>
                {
                questions?.length && (
                        questions?.map((question,index)=>{
                            return  <div className='question-pointer' onClick={() => setQuestionIndex(index)}>{index+1}</div>
                        })
                )
                }
            </div>
            <div className='quiz-info'>
               <div className='row-1'>
                  <p>Attempted</p>
                  <div className='attempt-count'>
                    {ansMap?.size}
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div className='row-1'>
                  <p>Unattempted</p>
                  <div className='unattempt-count'>
                    {questions?.length-ansMap?.size}
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='quiz-page-right'>
           
           <QuizQuestionCard 
             quesObj={questions[questionIndex]} 
             ansMap={ansMap}  
             setAnsMap={setAnsMap} 
             marks={marks} 
             setMarks={setMarks} 
             marksPerQues={marksPerQues} 
             negMarksPerQues={negMarksPerQues}
           />
           <div className='quiz-button'>

               <button 
                className='prev'
                onClick={()=>{
                    setQuestionIndex(questionIndex===0?0:questionIndex-1)
                }}
              > 
                Prev
              </button>

              <button 
               className='next'
               onClick={()=>{
                 setQuestionIndex(questionIndex===questions?.length-1?questionIndex:questionIndex+1)
               }}
              >  
                Next
              </button>
            
              <button className='submit-quiz' onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
           </div>
           {
              duration>0 && (
                <button className='timer'><QuizTimer ref={countdownRef} onComplete={handleTimerComplete} duration={duration} /></button>
              )
           }
        </div>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Quizpage


*** This the code of the QuizTimer ***
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown';

const formatNumber = (number) => String(number).padStart(2, '0');
const QuizTimer = forwardRef(({ onComplete, duration}, ref) => {
    
    const renderer = ({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
        
        if (completed) {
            onComplete();
            return <span>Time's up!</span>;
        } else {
           
            return (
                <span>
                     {formatNumber(hours)}:{formatNumber(minutes)}:{formatNumber(seconds)}
                </span>
            );
        }
    };

    return (
        <Countdown
            ref={ref}
            date={Date.now() + duration*60*1000} 
            renderer={renderer}
            onComplete={onComplete}
            autoStart={true}
           
        />
    );
});

export default QuizTimer;


It is a quiz page and I want when I visit the next and previous question by click on next button and previous button respectively the timer should not reset but right now it resets when I click on the previous or next button . The problem is it is reset whenever We click on the button that are render on the web page. I want to know how can i stop the reset of the timer when I click for next or previous question.
